# Appending p-values to correlation matrix dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to create a correlation matrix with the p-value right next to the correlation, but I am not sure how to merge the two.

My code:

```
library(psych)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
    col1 = rnorm(10),
    col2 = rnorm(10),
    col3=rnorm(10)
)
cors<-corr.test(df)
outputDF<-as.data.frame(cors$r)[lower.tri(cors$r,diag=FALSE),]
p.val <- (cors$p)[lower.tri(cors$p)]
View(outputDF)
```

My goal (p-values may be incorrect due to an R issue on my end):

```
        col1      col2
col2 -0.37(0.283)   
col3 -0.71(0.019) 0.60(0.06)
```

Comment: @akrun, that worked perfectly. If you will propose it as a solution I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `paste` to paste the corresponding elements in 'cors$r' and 'cors$p'.  By using `[]` we get the same structure as the `cors$p`. Change the elements in the diagonal and upper triangular matrix to `''` and subset the rows and columns that have at least one non-empty element.

```
res <- cors$p
res[] <- paste0(round(cors$r,2), "(", round(cors$p,2), ")")
res[upper.tri(res, diag=TRUE)] <- ''
res[!!rowSums(res!=''),!!colSums(res!='')]
#     col1          col2       
#col2 "-0.38(0.28)" ""         
#col3 "-0.72(0.02)" "0.6(0.06)"
```